# "warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]" and program does not work

Tags: c++, string, unicode, utf-8

So, I am writing program to translate runes to english alphabet
it gives me warning "warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]"
here is the code (not from the program but it has same problem) 
code is in c++

`string s = "ᛡᚣ";` (string of two utf-8 letters, runes)

`if(s.at(0) == 'ᛡ')
cout<<"YES";`

but warning is not the main problem, problem is that when i run it it does not output "YES", in case of a program when i try to translate Runes to alphabet it just starts working and makes bunch endl functions rather than translating runes (basically it does nothing)

P.S I tried using different compailers, in visual studio error poped up "Debug Assertion Failed!" "Expression: string subscript out of range"
other compailers just do nothing, i even tried to build program by using unicode instead of characters like "\u16B3".... but it's same, so what should i do? Do i need specific library for utf-8? pls help

Comment: As compiler explain, you use multi-character constant, which is so a int which implementation specific value. You have to compare several characters when using utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the representation of the characters in your `std::string` you'll see that each of the characters uses multiple bytes - hence the warning. When dealing with Unicode you'll either need to use something with 32 bits to represent individual code points or you need to use multiple bytes for each code point. The use of code points is *probably* sufficient but does rely on the characters not using combining characters.

Comparing Unicode strings isn't entirely trivial (and I don't know all the rules). When representing the data using UTF-8 you'll need to compare byte sequences. In addition, you need to make sure that your Unicode string is normalized: some string have different valid representations. For example the u-umlaut in my name can be represented with a code point for u-umlaut or with a code point for u and combining character for the dieresis. In your your code I'd guess you could use

```
std::string expect("ᛡ");
if (expect.size() <= s.size() && s.substr(0, expect.size()) == expect)
    std::cout << "YES\n";
```

Comment: how can i use this in for cycle? like if i have string=""ᚠᚢᚦᚩᚱᚳᚷᚹᚻᚾᛁᛂᛇᛈᛉᛋᛏᛒᛖᛗᛚᛝᛟᛞᚪᚫᚣᛡᛠ"; and want to convert to alphabet?

Comment: @IntotheVoid: it depends on what you intend to do. For finding a specific character you could use the `std::string` version if `find()` member. If you intend to do any form of string and/or character processing you'll probably need to deal with the encoding, most likely using a suitable Unicode library like ICU.